# How do I move the status icons to the top?

Tags: gnome, gui

I'm not sure of any of the terminology, so I'll have to explain things simply, to make sure you understand what I'm saying.

I'm using Gnome 3, and when I bring the mouse to the bottom right of the screen, a bar pops up, with icons of some things that are running in the background (at the moment, mine has "Update Manager", "Removable Devices", "caffeine-cup").

Is there any way to move these items to the bar at the top of the screen, alongside the icons for volume, network connectivity and universal access (how do I get rid of that btw)?

Comment: For removing the Universal Access button, try the [Accessibility Remover](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/112) extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is! :)

Install the extension [Status Icon Fixer](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/192/status-icon-fixer/).

Then go to the extension's file and edit with a text editor.

```
$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/status@gnome-shell.2jk.org
```

Or:

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/status@gnome-shell.2jk.org
```

Inside `extension.js` you'll find a line like `function enable() {`.

After that line, add a line with what you want to be on the top bar:

```
StatusIconDispatcher.STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS['audacious'] = 'audacious';
```

Remove `audacious` and put what you want.

Another example:

```
StatusIconDispatcher.STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS['dropbox'] = 'dropbox';
```